# Chrome packaged App notifications when the app is not running

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is there any way to show notifications from my packaged app even if it's not running? I've looked into the alarms API (http://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms.html) but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Rich Notifications API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications.html). It seems unlikely you didn't know that, though, so I'm going to guess you're asking how to run code when your app isn't running. As you said in your question, alarms are one of many ways to do this. Set an alarm, and in the event listener for that alarm, you'll pop up a rich notification. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Yep, I was looking to show a notification when my app is not running.  I've mistakenly thought that alarms work only if the app is running.

Comment: I also found that the alarms have to be created in one of the background JavaScript files to show these type of notifications.